# Convert date format

Tags: objective-c, json, ios, date-formatting

I am stuck with something here. I get the following date format from my JSON file:

```
2011-05-08 00:00:00
```

I need to convert this into

```
"May 8"
```

Help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
NSDateFormatter *formater = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formater setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss"];
NSDate *date2 = [formater dateFromString:@"2011-05-08 00:00:00"];
[formater setDateFormat:@"MMM d"];
NSString *result = [formater stringFromDate:date2];
```

Comment: The date formats in your answer seemed wrong. I've edited it.